# Draw image and text into a single image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

I'm attempting to combine both an image and a text field into a single image whilst still keeping the texts initial positioning.

I'm using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to create a bitmap context and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` to draw the final image.

So far, I have the following contained within a function:

```
let size = CGSize(width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(takenImage.size, false, takenImage.scale)

    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
    takenImage.draw(in: areaSize)

    let imageViewSize = self.takenImage.size
    let multiWidth = areaSize.width / imageViewSize.width
    let multiHeight = areaSize.height / imageViewSize.height
    print ("multiWidth = \(multiWidth)")
    print ("multiHeight = \(multiHeight)")

    let textSize = CGRect(x: textOverlay.frame.origin.x * multiWidth, y: textOverlay.frame.origin.y * multiHeight, width: textOverlay.frame.size.width * multiWidth, height: textOverlay.frame.size.height * multiHeight)
    textOverlay.drawText(in: textSize)

    let outputImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.finalImage = outputImage
```

`takenImage` is the taken image from my camera (**never** null) and `textOverlay` is a `UITextField` containing the wanted text.

I first create the bitmap and draw `takenImage` using both its original width/height.

If I draw just this to my `finalImage`, all works fine. The problem stems from trying to add the text and keep it in the same position.

I've tried to create a second `CGRect` with x, y, w, h coordinates from the `UITextField : textOverlay` but when viewing the final image, I'm getting weird results.

The images can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18JWR.jpg).

How would I go about preserving the text's position in the merged image?

Comment: try `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(takenImage.size, false, takenImage.scale)`

Comment: Doesn't change anything @LeoDabus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need recalculate area size to draw text.

```
let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
takenImage.draw(in: areaSize)

let imageViewSize = self.imageView.size
let multiWidth = areaSize.width / imageViewSize.width
let multiHeight = areaSize.height / imageViewSize.height

let textSize = CGRect(x: textOverlay.frame.origin.x * multiWidth, y: textOverlay.frame.origin.y * multiHeight, width: textOverlay.frame.size.width * multiWidth, height: textOverlay.frame.size.height * multiHeight)
textOverlay.drawText(in: textSize)
```

Here, I use `self.imageView` - it is imageView contains your `takenImage`. 
Hope it help.

Comment: Just tried this, still getting the same outputting image. Somehow the text coordinates are not being used.

Comment: Can you debug value of `multiWidth ` and `multiHeight `?

Comment: Both width/height = 1.0

Comment: Hey. Wrong is here. I use `let imageViewSize = self.imageView.size` not the `let imageViewSize = self.takenImage.size`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137884/discussion-between-dipper-and-luan-tran).